# How to Filter comments on my posts in groups on Facebook?

Tags: facebook-groups

I often miss comments on posts I have made to FB groups. I'd like to filter/search for just those.

Any way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

OK, go to the search box to the upper right text box to search any post or keyword that has been posted in that group then hit enter you will see what you're looking. hope this was helpful. :)